# Django: How to sort a table presented in the front end by one particular column

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a data model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The template is:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display dataTable" id="list">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Uptime</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for task in tasks|dictsortreversed:"uptime" %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{task.id}}</td>
        <td>{{task.uptime}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And I wish the table presented in the front end to be sorted by the uptime.

I have tried dictsort. But it didn't work. Now, if I click on the title of Uptime, it seems that the table treated data in this column as string and sorted the rows in alphabetical order
[image: rows sorted in the alphabetical order]

Question is: How to sort this table by the time in the Uptime field

Answer (score 1):

I know about two variants:

1. Provide **your_view** where sorting content base on "uptime" or "-uptime":

   ```
   class TaskListView(ListView):
       model = Task
       paginate_by = 10

       def get_queryset(self):
           queryset = super(TaskListView, self).get_queryset()
           if self.kwargs.get('sort'):
               sort_by = self.kwargs.get('sort')
               return queryset.order_by(sort_by)
           return queryset
   ```

   Then in Html in your header table:

   ```
   <th>
   {% if view.kwargs.sort == "uptime" %}
       href="{% url "task_sort" 'uptime' %}">Uptime</a>
   {% else %}
       <a href="{% url "task_sort**" '-uptime' %}">Uptime</a>
   {% endif %}
   </th>
   ```

   In the urls.py:

   ```
   path('task_list/<str:sort>/', TaskListView.as_view(), name='task_sort')
   ```
2. If you need something massive and sort through many columns it's better to use additional packages https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/